# Split based on | in R

Tags: r, split

I want to split 10000P04|D8514589|48621679|401|Shock00_Base based on the following | symbol. I use the following code:

> strsplit("10000P04|D8514589|48621679|401|Shock00_Base", "|")

However this produces:

```
[[1]][1] "1" "0" "0" "P" "8" "7" "|" "0" "4" "6" "0" "3" "|" "0" "4" "6" "0" "3" "0" "0" "0" "3" "5" "|" "2" "0" "1" "|" "S" "h" "o" "c" "k" "0" "0" "_" "B" "a" "s" [40] "e"
```

It seems R does not recognize the | character. Does anybody know how the split is conducted?

Kind regards

Comment: You need to escape the `|` symbol, since it has a special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: strsplit("10000P04|D8514589|48621679|401|Shock00_Base", "\\|").  The "|" is the REGEX code for "or".  You need to escape it with "\\".

Comment: Another option is to add the argument `fixed=TRUE`

Comment: Someone (@stomper or the OP), please post the info from these comments as an answer ...

Comment: Another option if `X` is the character string is `read.csv(text=X, sep="|", header=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "|" is the REGEX code for "or". You need to escape it with "\".

```
strsplit("10000P04|D8514589|48621679|401|Shock00_Base", "\\|")

[[1]]
[1] "10000P04"     "D8514589"     "48621679"     "401"          "Shock00_Base"
```